# Am having a problem recording my project on the Cypress Dashboard

Tags: javascript, cypress

Prior to trying to record my project on the Cypress Dashboard my code was working fine

1. I was using Cypress version 10 and i also tried version 9 which did not help either.
2. As required I added the projectId into the cypress.config.js
3. And i ran the command npx cypress run --record --key a69743f6-085b-449b-89e6-06f12ed88a3b

I keep getting the error

'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT

```
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)

at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)

at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

{

errno: -4058,

code: 'ENOENT',

syscall: 'spawn cmd',

path: 'cmd',

spawnargs: [

```
'/c',

'WMIC path win32_process get Name,Processid,ParentProcessId,Commandline,ExecutablePath'
```

]
}

please i need some help on how to go about it. tnks